# Com ConstraintLayout não se usa mais match_parent?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-responsivo

Com o recurso de ConstraintLayout não se usa mais match_parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa/pode usar sim, porque:

- [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) herda de [ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup), que é a classe base para todos os tipos de layout.
- Qualquer layout tem de ter as sua dimensões definidas.
- O valor das dimensões pode ser um valor inteiro ou uma das constantes MATCH_PARENT / WRAP_CONTENT. Elas representam o valor `ffffffff` e `fffffffe` respectivamente.

Tal como a qualquer ViewGroup ao ConstraintLayout pode ser necessário indicar, em vez de definir uma dimensão fixa, que este adapte as suas dimensões ás do seu contentor ou ás do seu conteúdo.